# In File Provider extension for iOS 11, I want to enable my app's passcode for user to access the files

Tags: ios11, fileprovider-extension

I have enabled passcode option in my app but when I enable it the files app doesn't ask me the passcode when I access the documents through Files app.
I have gone through all of the documents available for the File provider extension but reached nowhere. please help if anyone worked on this?

Also, let me know if any other info is required from my end.

Comment: Maybe a little too late, but I’ve got a solution: you need to add FileProviderUI extension, which may be called from FileProvider to present some custom UI. In that FileProviderUI process you can request the passcode from the user and ping your FileProvider process when the correct password is entered - by either altering some flag in shared storage or sending cross-process Darwin notification